# Multiplication table - C

Tags: c, nested-loops

I want to display multiplication table which will look like this:

```
    1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8   
1   1x1=1   
2   1x2=2   2x2=4   
3   1x3=3   2x3=6   3x3=9   
4   1x4=4   2x4=8   3x4=12  4x4=16  
5   1x5=5   2x5=10  3x5=15  4x5=20  5x5=25  
6   1x6=6   2x6=12  3x6=18  4x6=24  5x6=30  6x6=36  
7   1x7=7   2x7=14  3x7=21  4x7=28  5x7=35  6x7=42  7x7=49  
8   1x8=8   2x8=16  3x8=24  4x8=32  5x8=40  6x8=48  7x8=56  8x8=64
```

So far I have something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int row,col;

       if(n<1 || n>9)
    {
        printf("input error");
        return 0;
    }

    for (row=0; row<=n;row++){
        if(row==0)
        {
            for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                printf("\t%d", i);
            }
        }

        for(col=0; col<=row;col++)
        {
            if(col==0 && row>0)
            printf("%d\t", row);
            if(row>=1 && col!=0)
            printf("%dx%d=%d\t", col, row, col*row);
        }
        if(row!=n)
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think it displays the table properly, but the code looks sloppy and I'm sure it can be done in a much cleaner way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't that question be better for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd unroll the first pass through each of the loops that displays the row & column headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int row,col;

    if(n<1 || n>9)
    {
        printf("input error");
        return 0;
    }


    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", i);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    for (row=1; row<=n;row++){

        printf("%d\t", row);
        for(col=1; col<=row;col++)
        {
            printf("%dx%d=%d\t", col, row, col*row);
        }

        if (row!=n)
            printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of what makes your code look sloppy is simply bad style. Here are a few tips based on what is generally considered good style and best practice:

- Print a prompt whenever your program is getting input from the user
- Put all variable declarations together at the top of the main function
- Use parenthesis to make the order of operations clear, especially when using the `&&` and `||` operators
- Make error messages clear
- return a negative value to indicate an error
- Put a space on both sides of binary operators (i.e. "`n < 1`" as opposed to "`n<1`")
- Put a space after commas when declaring multiple variables
- Put a space after semi-colons in for loop conditions
- The following is generally considered a good-style `for` loop:

  ```
  for (condition) {
     ...
  }
  ```
- The following is generally considered a good-style `if` statement

  ```
  if (condition) {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Use comments to explain your code and increase readability
- Use indentation to show code grouping

Aside from all of these things, your program also does not print a newline after the very last row (row `n`) due to the very final if statement. This causes the user's command-line prompt to be displayed on the same line as the last row printed by your program, which is probably not desirable.

Applying all of these things to your code gives the following result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // all variables declared together, at the top of main
    int n, i;
    int row, col; // space after comma

    printf("Enter multiplication table size: "); // prompt
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // better-style if statement
    if ((n < 1) || (n > 9)) { // parenthesis make the order of operations clearer
        // clearer error message, with a newline at the end
        printf("Error: table size must be at least 1 and not greater than 9\n");

        return -1; // return a negative value to indicate an error
    }

    // better-style for loop
    for (row = 0; row <= n; row++) { // spaces around binary operators, space after semi-colons
        // better-style if, indented also
        if (row == 0) {
            // better-style for, indented
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // spacing
                printf("\t%d", i); // indented
            }
        }

        // better-style for
        for (col = 0; col <= row; col++) { // spacing, indentation
            if ((col == 0) && (row>0)) // parenthesis, spacing, indentation
                printf("%d\t", row); // indentation
            if ((row >= 1) && (col != 0)) // parenthesis, spacing, indentation
                printf("%dx%d=%d\t", col, row, col * row); // indentation, spacing
        }

        // surrounding if statement removed, so a newline is printed after every row, including the last one
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I mainly used comments to explain the changes I made to your code, whereas you would want to use them to explain the functionality.